# NSPredicate concatenating attributes

Tags: objective-c, ios, nspredicate

I m trying to figure out how to concatenate attribute names. I have a county and a district attribute that I want to query like

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"county + district contains[cd] %@",searchBar.text]
```

gives me unimplemented SQL generation for predicate error. and I am not sure how to implement NSPredicate.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should give you an idea of how to do some more complicated searching. It will match queries for "county district", "district county", etc.

```
    NSArray *searchTerms = [searchBar.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSString *predicateFormat = @"(county contains[cd] %@) OR (district contains[cd] %@)";
    NSPredicate *predicate;
    if ([searchTerms count] == 1) {
        NSString *term = [searchTerms objectAtIndex:0];
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat, term, term];
    } else {
        NSMutableArray *subPredicates = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSString *term in searchTerms) {
            NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat, term, term];
            [subPredicates addObject:p];
        }
        predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];
    }
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

See [Cocoa Is My Girlfriend: Adding iTunes-style search to your Core Data application](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/11/25/adding-itunes-style-search-to-your-core-data-application/) for more explanation.

Comment: That is not equivalent. concatenating "ABC"+"DEF" would match "CDE". Your solution would not. I understand that in the OP context that is likely not an issue. It would be in mine. So the question stands: how do you concatenate 2 columns of an entity before matching?

Comment: I ended up adding a derived attribute that I compute to be the concatenation of the two source ones. I then have a predicate on that derived attribute. This wastes storage in my CoreData database, but that's a price I can pay in my case. I may have made it a transient attribute, but I'm not sure you can query on one. (TBH, I didn't even try)

Comment: @Jean-DenisMuys You can't when you are doing the initial querying from the SQLite store: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3553471/877032 (Also, I tried before I saw that answer and it didn't work)

Answer (score 3):

I ended up implementing another field as concatenating the two variables(district+country) and perform the query on that variable.

Comment: It would maybe be useful with a code snippet for people to learn from?

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar and concluded that like cekisakurek, the best method was to concatenate the fields into a common field (more relevant for first/last name)

```
- (NSString *)fullName {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstName, self.lastName];
}
```

and then filtered on this field using 'contains[cd]'

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fullName contains[cd] %@", self.searchBar.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"county contains[cd] %@ AND district contains[cd] %@",searchBar.text,searchBar.text];
```

Just try the above lines of code, it would helps you.

Comment: that would be an `OR` operator, if I understand the OP intent correctly

Comment: @Jean-DenisMuys in the question he specified Country + district thats why I used AND here

Comment: Fine. This doesn't answer the OP's original question however, which was "how to concatenate attribute [by] names [in predicates]?", even if the OP's didn't *mean* precisely that.