# Transient attributes and FetchRequest?

Tags: ios, entity, transient

I have a transient attribute `titleFirstLetter` in the Book Entity:

```
- (NSString *)titleFirstLetter 
{
    NSString *tmpValue = nil;

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"titleFirstLetter"];

    if ([[self title] length] > 0) {
        tmpValue = [[[self title] substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
        if ([[NSScanner scannerWithString:tmpValue] scanInt:NULL]) { //return # if its a number
            tmpValue = @"#";
        }
    } else { //sanity in case the attribute is not set.
        tmpValue = @"";
    }

    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"titleFirstLetter"];

    return tmpValue;
}
```

and I am trying to use this attribute as Section name but when I execute:

```
 // Create the sort descriptors array.
NSSortDescriptor *authorDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"titleFirstLetter" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *titleDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:authorDescriptor, titleDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

// Create and initialize the fetch results controller.
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"titleFirstLetter" cacheName:nil];
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',  
reason: 'keypath titleFirstLetter not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Book id=1>'
```

please help!

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3553471

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the section index, and don't want section headers, you can just pass the title attribute and it will achieve what you are looking for.

```
sectionNameKeyPath:@"title"
```

Otherwise, if you actually want section headers that have just the first letter, see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741093/how-to-use-the-first-character-as-a-section-name) for a full discussion.